# R: Get indices of all elements in a vector?

Tags: r, indexing

Simple questions, but I can't find an answer.

I have a vector

```
a<-c(5,6,7)
```

how can I get back the indices for all elements in my vector?

I need back

```
1  #"a"
2  #"b"
3  #"c"
```

or `c(1,2,3)`

If I run seq_along(a), it gives me back `(1,1,1)` not `(1,2,3)`:

```
for (i in seq_along(a)) {
  print(seq_along(a[[i]])) 
}

[1] 1
[1] 1
[1] 1
```

The reason for this is that I need to create a unique name for each of my plots. I have about 100 plots illustrating 100 locations. Locations'names are too long and contain special characters, thus I can't use them to name my output plots. I would like to use the index value to substitute the name for each saved plot.

My function that I need to modify:

```
lineCumRateGraph <- function(tab, na.rm = TRUE, ...) {

  # Create list of locations
  type_list <-unique(tab$uniqueLoc)

  # Create a for loop to produce ggplot plots
  for (i in seq_along(type_list)) {

    # create a plot for each loc in df
    plot<-

      ggplot(subset(tab, tab$uniqueLoc == type_list[i]),
             aes(x = factor(gridcode), 
                 y = cumRate) +
      geom_line(aes(linetype = distance),
                size = 1) +
      ggtitle(type_list[i])

    windows(width = 4, height = 3.5)
    print(plot)
    ggsave(plot,
           width = 3.5, height = 3.5,
           file = paste(outPath,
                        "lineCumRate",
                       # type_list[i], # I need to replace this one by index value
                        ".png",
                        sep=''),
           dpi = 300)
  }
}
```

Comment: Well, the indices for all elements of a vector are always going to be a sequence the length of your vector. But, I assume there's something more you're interested in?

Comment: if you want the values to be printed, in your loop, you should `print(i)` and not `print(seq_along(a[[i]]))`.

Comment: Or just type `seq_along(a)` in the console, or `print(seq_along(a))`.

Comment: Cool, thank you @Drj and @Renu! I know that has too be simple, it was hard day thought.. :-D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the purpose served by the `seq_along` function:

```
seq_along(a)
[1] 1 2 3
> cbind( seq_along(a), a)
         a  
[1,] "1" "a"
[2,] "2" "b"
[3,] "3" "c"
>  data.frame( sq = seq_along(a), a)
  sq a
1  1 a
2  2 b
3  3 c
```

Answer (score 1):

If you like something elementary, you can try:

```
a<-c(5,6,7)
b <- 1:length(a)
```

Comment: Although correct and intuitive, using this paradigm inside a for-loop iterator is notorious for difficult to understand errors in the situation where the length of a (missing or misspelled) vector is 0. Instead of returning a missing value, it returns `c(1,0)`.